# Exceptions in C# try catch throw

Tags: c#

I am handling exceptions in this program. Is this the correct way to handle exceptions?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment1
{
    class Calc
    {
        public static double n1;
        public static double n2;
        public static char op1;
        public static double result;

        public static void Calculate(String num1, String num2, String op)
        {
            op1 = Convert.ToChar(op);
            n1 = Convert.ToDouble(num1);
            n2 = Convert.ToDouble(num2);

            switch (op1)
            {
                case '+':
                    Console.WriteLine(Add());
                    break;

                case '-':
                    Console.WriteLine(Minus());
                    break;

                case '*':
                    Console.WriteLine(Multiply());
                    break;

                case '/':    // ******exception handling***** //

                    if (n2 == 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            throw new Exception("number 2 cannot be zero");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(Divide());
                    break;

                case '^':
                    Console.WriteLine(Power());
                    break;

                default:    // ******exception handling***** //
                    try
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Invalid Operator: Exception Handling");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        public static double Add()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Addition");
            result = n1 + n2;
            return result;
        }

        public static double Minus()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Subtraction");
            result = n1 - n2;
            return result;
        }

        public static double Multiply()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Multiplication");
            result = n1 * n2;
            return result;
        }

        public static double Divide()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Division");
            result = n1 / n2;
            return result;
        }

        public static double Power()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("X power of n");
            result = Math.Pow(n1, n2);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I do not want to use the built-in divide by zero exception for division as it doesn't work for the *double* data type.

I also want to get an exception when the user enters an invalid operator. So I have used an exception handler in the default case.

I am taking the user input in the main function and then passing the inputs to calculate the function as parameters from *main*.

Can I make any changes to make this program more efficient?

Comment: This is the third or fourth time I've seen this exact assignment in the last couple days. You all need better assignments (or a better instructor)

Comment: Looks ok to me. You throw an exception, catch and log it. What do you want to improve?

Comment: And no, that's not proper exception handling... If you are just going to throw the exception and do nothing else in the `try` in order to catch the exception you just threw so you can output a message (the `default` case), skip it all and output the message directly. In the case of division, because you swallow the exception and don't do anything else (`break`, for example) `Divide()` still gets called when `n2==0`. You could wrap the whole method in a single try/catch.. Then at least throwing the exceptions would have some meaning to them

Comment: Unless you are writing say a _plug-in framework where you must ensure that potentially unsafe 3rd party exceptions don't bubble across to the main AppDomain_ you should **avoid** doing `catch (Exception e)`

Comment: If `num1` or `num2` do not `Convert.ToDouble()` correctly, an exception will be thrown long before your `try()...catch()` incidentally.

Answer (score 2):

No, your code is **not** ok. Throwing exceptions only to catch **all** types of exceptions on the next line, only to eat it, serves zero purpose!

Consider your code:

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid Operator: Exception Handling");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

That is essentially the same as:

```
Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator: Exception Handling");
```

...apart from throwing a first-chance exception in the debugger.

Generally, you want to do something like this:

```
try
{
    var x = Divide (9, 3);
    x = Divide (14, 2.3f); 
    Divide(10, 0);  // bang!
}
catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

.
.
.
float Divide (float n, float d)
{
    return n / d;
}
```

OP:

> Can I make any changes to make this program more efficient?

Yes.  Only throw exceptions for things that are "out of the ordinary" or exceptional (pun intended) cases.  **Do not use exceptions as a means to direct flow control**. While throwing exceptions is computationally *cheap*, the transition to what is inside the `catch` isn't, thus making it considerably slower than a simple `if/else` in your particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You do not require a try catch block in the case `n2 == 0` . When you already have an `if` statement validating n2's value, you are avoiding the error in the first place. Basically you have two options, either use the if statement or either use the try catch block. The recommended approach would to be validate your data, relying on try catch blocks primarily isn't a decent approach to adopt.
Now for your options

Option 1:

```
public static void Calculate(String num1, String num2, String op)
{

   //Code

        switch (op1)
        {
          //Code
            case '/':    //******exception handling*****//

            if (n2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("number 2 cannot be zero");
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Divide());
            break;

            default:    //******exception handling*****//
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator: Exception Handling");
                break;
          }
}
```

Option 2:

```
public static void Calculate(String num1, String num2, String op)
{

    //Code

        switch (op1)
        {
          //Code
            case '/':    //******exception handling*****//

            try{
                Divide(); //Whatever your dividing method is
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            default:    //******exception handling*****//
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator: Exception Handling");
                break;
          }
}
```

**Remember that `Try Catch` is used to catch exceptions, not to throw them.**

Comment: thaks,but i wont get any message saying that my denominator is zero when i use your code.@afnan makhdoom

Comment: You would, read the line:

           ` if (n2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("number 2 cannot be zero");
                break;
            }`

Comment: default:
                    try
                    {

                        throw new Exception("Invalid Operator: Exception Handling");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                    break;         //***** how to handle my default case that is want to use exceptions and print exception handling message if user enters other operator. *****//

Comment: in my code, it tells the user than an invalid character was entered: Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operator: Exception Handling");